# Visualizar elementos de Jcombox a un Jtable

Tags: java, java-swing

Saludos cordiales tengo un jcombobox mat_codigo,mat_des,mat_preciovta necesito pasar los valores a un jtable como la descripcion en la columna (1) y el precio vta en la coulman (3) como esta en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo es el sgte:
 public void MostrarComboBoxCategoria() {
     DefaultComboBoxModel value1;
     try {
            Statement sent = Conn.createStatement();

```
     String sql = "select mat_codigo,mat_des,mat_preciov from materiales order by mat_codigo asc";
     ResultSet rs = sent.executeQuery(sql);

      value1 = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
     cmb_cat.setModel(value1);

     while (rs.next()) {
         value1.addElement(new CmbObtener(rs.getString("mat_des"), rs.getString("mat_codigo"),rs.getString("mat_preciov")));

     }
       rs.close();
      Conn.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getCause());

    }}
```

public class CmbObtener {

```
private String datoItem;
private String id;
private String preciov;

public CmbObtener(String datoItem, String id,String preciov) {
    this.datoItem = datoItem;
    this.id = id;
    this.preciov=preciov;
}

public String getID() {
    return id;
}

public String toString() {
    return datoItem;
}
public String getpreciov() {
    return preciov;
}


}
```

Pero no se visuliza el jcombox en la jtable. Agradezco su cordial apoyo.saluds

Answer (score 0):

Bueno encontré una solución rápida editando el Table contents y agregue al custom code del editor de la jtable

new javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor(cmb_cat), ahora visualiza el elemento recorrdio de mi tabla en la Base de Datos, pero necesito enviar a la columna 03 del jtable el precio de venta según se muestra en la figura.